# How to install certificate for localhost or using ipaddress?

Tags: java, linux, installation, x509certificate

I have an web app running on lets say following IP : `10.101.10.101`. 
web app name is is example so the whole URL is like : `https://10.101.10.101/example`

Now tried to install certificate using this command : `java InstallCert 10.101.10.101/example` but getting this error : `Number format exception.`

How can I achieve this ?

**Note** - However I am successfully able to run this in windows using this command : `10.101.10.101/example`

Comment: Do you have the the source for InstallCert?

Comment: yes. I have. See this link for your reference.[link](http://code.google.com/p/java-use-examples/source/browse/trunk/src/com/aw/ad/util/InstallCert.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your command to:

```
java InstallCert "10.101.10.101"
```

Comment: I tried this itself very first time and also it seems to be working in windows but not in linux.

Comment: Did you try putting the argument in quotes?